# Error: The connection "" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

Tags: ssis

I have an Execute SQL task in my package which calls a stored procedure.
when i run the package, it throws the following error

```
Error: The connection "" is not found. 
This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
```

The maximum error count has reached but still the package doesn't stop instead the component remains in Yellow color. And if I stop the package and re-run it, it runs successfully.

Does the error means that during my previous run the **Maximum Timeout time for the server has been crossed?**

Comment: Does the package use configurations or have some other parameter/expression driven connection?    That error would indicate to me that you don't have a connection manager configured in the SQL Task or that the connection is missing OR that there is another reference from a task or step that references a connection manager that is no longer present.

Comment: There are no Expressions with the Task or with the connection string and there are no Configurations associated with the package. Some of the tasks that uses the same connection does works fine. Also when I ran the package again, there was no problem with the Task for which the error occurred previously instead the same error occurred when another component was running.

Comment: So, is this still an issue?  Or does this happen intermittently?

Comment: It is intermittent. I suspect it is because of the server that I try to connect. Because when I try to run the same SP with SSMS I find it running for a long time than usual.

Comment: This is an older post, but it has instructions on the SSIS connection manager ConnectionTimeout property. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/11/30/sql-server-configuration-timeouts-and-a-workaround-ssis.aspx